# Post process each entire page to move/resize contents

Tags: pdftex, scaling, rendering

LaTeX beginner here.

I am looking to physically print a rendered document on a size that is not 8.5 x 11. My printer can only handle that size, and does strange things to smaller pdf's. However. If I feed smaller paper, it prints as expected.

Thus, I would like to render a pdf at 8.5 x 11, but have the content be (let's say) 3.5 x 4.5. Basically, like this [image: this]

I would like for whatever would have been rendered on the page to be scaled and moved like this to the top and left of the page, regardless of what content is rendered on that page.

Using a separate program to achieve this would be acceptable as well.

Comment: May I suggest you to have a look at the _geometry_ package?  It allows you to specify the page boundaries with great flexibility and ease.  You could set them as you need and solve your problem in a single LaTeX run.  But maybe I am misunderstanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I am actually looking to process the PDF after the fact. Good to know, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this in a 2-step process.  First, create the full size PDF as usual, then include that PDF in a new Latex run using `pdfpages`.  `pdfpages` allows scaling and offsets.

sample.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Final latex document that includes sample.tex.  Play around with the `scale` and `offset` dimensions to get what you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[scale=0.5,pages=-,offset=-2.3in 3in]{sample.pdf}
\end{document}
```